# Building a string and running it in terminal python

Tags: python, string, wget

Hey guys I'm creating a python script to download youtube videos.  I know I could do it in native linux scripting language, but I'm trying to learn how to do scripts in python since in my work, I use Windowns.

until now I have

```
import os

print("starting script....\n")
link = raw_input('add link\n')
name = name = raw_input('add the name with flv extension\n')
command = 'wget -O ' + name + ' $(youtube-dl -g ' + link + ' )'
os.system("command")
```

I think that the simple (" ' ") are the problem.  How can I write it to work ?

Thank you !!

Comment: Why are you trying to combine `wget` and `youtube-dl`? The latter would be sufficient to download videos by itself. Just call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have

```
os.system("command")
```

which is trying to run the command "command" instead of the wget command

Try this instead:

```
import os

print("starting script....\n")
link = raw_input('add link\n')
name = name = raw_input('add the name with flv extension\n')
command = 'wget -O ' + name + ' $(youtube-dl -g ' + link + ' )'
os.system(command)
```